# How to get rid of horizontal scroll bar when shrinking window?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

Using the HTML and CSS below, you'll notice that rather than shrinking to fit the browser window, the site gets a horizontal scroll bar when shrunk down to 189px width. I've gone through my code and I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening. Keep in mind I'm a newbie so I might very well have overlooked something.

Also, I have a bonus question if that is allowed: I want to shrink the menu height but it seems impossible. How would you go about it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
<a href="#">about</a> <br>
<a href="#">contact</a> <br>
<a href="#">donate</a> <br>
      </div>

      <div class="pic">
<img src="roshi.jpg" alt="roshi">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
<h1>Article</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<h1>Article</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content2">
<h1>Article</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<h1>Article</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
Footer
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
html body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;

}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header"
  "menu"
  "pic"
  "content"
  "content2"
  "footer";
}


.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.header h1 {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 2;

}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;

}
.menu a:link {
  color: black;
}
.pic {
  grid-area: pic;

}

img {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.content {
  grid-area: content;

}
.content2 {
  grid-area: content2;
}
.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: lightgrey;

}

.wrapper > * {
  margin: 0px 30px;
}
.header, .footer {

  padding: 0px 30px;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-areas:
"header header"
"menu menu"
"pic pic"
"content content2"
"footer footer";
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.menu a {
  padding-right: 10px;

}
}
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/tzrqf5np/

Comment: try to give your picture the width of auto instead of 100%. Then it will auto set the width to the maximum possible. a width of 100% goes 100% of the parent width ignoring margin and paddings in the width calculation. Also try to add a `grid-auto-rows: auto` that way the height of every row will only get the height that is needed within the larges column in the same row.

Comment: PS: Fixed the code as you wanted in my anwser and its good to see that you started to work grids and already taking advantages of it with the use of media query. Very pro like.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed your CSS as you wanted. You really should start making sure you get your spacings right. it has no direct influence in HTML and CSS but helps reading and is a good practise for other languages. There plently languages where spacings make a difference if a code works or not. But having it easier to read espacially with programs like Visual Studio Code the advantage is that you see which closing tags belong to which starting tag.
Please try to practice it for me "my little padawan" :P

Ok One change of formatting was to the media query:

```css
@media only screen
  and ...
  and ... {
    body {
      random-code: xy;
    }
}
```

espacilly if you use media query to adress screens use `only screen`. Even it works nearly always take it as a good habit same as getting your spacings right. Then get a new line with `and...` what every you want to use. you can combine that way many rules like `min-width` and `max-width`, `orientation: landscape/portrait` screen format...

then you used: `grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;` I switched it to `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` and added the `grid-auto-rows: auto;` and tada: its working. The menu is way smaller just like you wanted.

Next the picture got a width of auto. that way it shouldnt create a horizontal scrollbar. a width of 100% will as it will add the 100% to the margin and paddings on top and then the width is wider then the screen.

```css
html body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header"
  "menu"
  "pic"
  "content"
  "content2"
  "footer";
}


.header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.header h1 {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  padding: 0;

}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:link {
  color: black;
}

.pic {
  grid-area: pic;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
}

.content2 {
  grid-area: content2;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.wrapper > * {
  margin: 0px 30px;
}

.header, .footer {
  padding: 0px 30px;
}

@media only screen 
  and (min-width: 500px) {
    .wrapper {
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-auto-rows: auto;
      grid-template-areas:
        "header header"
        "menu menu"
        "pic pic"
        "content content2"
        "footer footer";
    }
    
    .menu {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      margin-left: auto;
    }

    .menu a {
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="header">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#">about</a><br>
        <a href="#">contact</a><br>
        <a href="#">donate</a>
      </div>
      <div class="pic">
        <img src="roshi.jpg" alt="roshi">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Article</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <h1>Article</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content2">
        <h1>Article</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <h1>Article</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will practice my spacings for you, I promise:-)

Thanks a lot for having a look at the code and thanks for teaching me grids, they make things much more logical and easier to understand from a beginners point of view I think. I'm trying to use them in a lot of practice-designs now, because I feel like once I got them all the way down, I will be pretty well covered in the basics of CSS layouting.